# selenium driver, option inside optgroup fails to execute

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the PHP webdriver bindings here:
http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/

I can select standard `option` elements in a `<select>` no problem, but when they are a child of an `<optgroup>` the click() method doesn't change the selected item.

The element is found (i can `var_dump` the details of the element). The code I am using is:

```
$xpath = "//select[@name='{$element}']/optgroup[@label='{$optgrp}']/option[@value='{$value}']";
$element = $this->_webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, $xpath);
$element->click();
```

If I then do the below, it will fail.

```
$this->assertTrue($element->isSelected());
```

Comment: Thanks for your question - it showed me how to set up the xpath correctly.  Not sure about the assert, but it works when I invoke ->click() on a select list