# how to get options under a particular optgroup using selenium web driver for java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to select options under particular optgroup from a multiselect picklist field, for example

```
<select id="xyz">
   <optgroup label="Group1">
      <option value="1">pick1</option>
      <option value="2">pick2</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Group2">
       <option value="3">pick3</option>
       <option value="4">pick4</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

if the picklist field is like above, I can use

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"))).selectByVisibleText("pick1");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"))).selectByVisibleText("pick2");
```

for selecting all the options which is under optgroup -Group1 from the above.

Here I know which are all the options present in the Group1 and hence I can select like above.

But my requirement is dynamically I need to select all the options under optgroup-Group1.

If I want to select all the options both including Group 1 & 2 dynamically

Then I can use

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"))).getOptions();
```

to get all options as a List and I can store it as an array, and I can select all the Options one by one using array

But how can I get all the options under only one specific optgroup say Group1 or Group2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use **xpath** and `findElements`:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath = "//select[@id='xyz']/optgroup[@label='Group1']/option")))
```

Comment: Thanks asgoth,  As I was busy with some other work, today only I can tried with your answer its working fine.

Comment: For me the path there was not enough (but did get me thinking about the right direction .. thank you for the pointer).  The xpath in this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/9670804/2162226 worked for me.  Here's a complete example that worked for me - notice additional info after 'option' : //select[@id='edit-source']/optgroup[@label='SourceGroup1']/option[@value='4']