# Selenium Java - Select option under optgroup

Tags: selenium, optgroup

I have an element with 2 optgroups, each one has several options (some of the options exist in both optgroups

[image: code]

I need to find one of the options.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170713/how-to-get-options-under-a-particular-optgroup-using-selenium-web-driver-for-jav)

Comment: @GauravGenius
Tried that one.
Didn't work for me.
Was trying to use it with select, but it says that this is 'option'.
Tried also to click it (without select), but then it says that the element is not visible.